# How to pass a passphrase to ssh-add without triggering a prompt?

Tags: bash, command-line

I read `man ssh-add` and I don't see a flag for passing a passphrase <strike>like we have in `ssh` which is `-p`</strike>.

I tried

```
# the -K is for macOS's ssh-add but it's not relevant
ssh-add -q -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa <<< $passphrase
```

But I get the following output:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

How can I pass a password w/o triggering a prompt

**Update**

Adding more context to what I'm doing, I'm creating a script to create SSH keys for me. It will generate the passphrase, the SSH key using that passphrase, and add it to the agent.

```bsh
# ...
passphrase=$(generate_password)

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C $email -f $filename -N $passphrase -q
ssh-add -q -K $filename
```

Following Stephen's answer, I'm not sure how would that work. Seems like I'd had to create a temporal script and save it to disk, in order for SSH_ASKPASS to work. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI wrt temporary files & co: the here-string syntax (`<<< $passphrase`) will use a temporary file and store the passphrase into it (at least in bash, ksh and zsh)

Comment: Warning: passing data on the command-line, may expose it to other processes on the same machine. Also consider: do you need a passphrase?

Comment: You could use Homebrew to install ssh-askpass

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90853

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the `ssh-add` manpage:

```
 DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS
         If ssh-add needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from
         the current terminal if it was run from a terminal.  If ssh-add
         does not have a terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and
         SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the program specified by
         SSH_ASKPASS (by default ``ssh-askpass'') and open an X11 window
         to read the passphrase.  This is particularly useful when calling
         ssh-add from a .xsession or related script.  (Note that on some
         machines it may be necessary to redirect the input from /dev/null
         to make this work.)
```

So we can use this to cheat a little.

We start with no identities in the agent:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

So now we need a program that will supply the password:

```
$ cat x
#!/bin/sh
echo test123
```

And then convince ssh-add to use that script:

```
$ DISPLAY=1 SSH_ASKPASS="./x" ssh-add test < /dev/null
Identity added: test (sweh@godzilla)
```

And there it is:

```
$ ssh-add -l                                          
2048 SHA256:07qZby7TafI10LWAMSvGFreY75L/js94pFuNcbhfSC0 sweh@godzilla (RSA)
```

Edit to add, based on revised question:

The password could be passed as a variable, and the askpass script use that variable.

For example:

```
$ cat /usr/local/sbin/auto-add-key
#!/bin/sh
echo $SSH_PASS

$ SSH_PASS=test123 DISPLAY=1 SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/local/sbin/auto-add-key ssh-add test < /dev/null
Identity added: test (sweh@godzilla)
```

In the workflow presented you would do `SSH_PASS=$passphrase` to use the newly generated passphrase.

Comment: Possible improvement: ssh-add will endlessly loop calling the SSH_ASKPASS program if password was bad, consider making auto-add-key exit if `$1` starts with Bad (full content is "Bad passphrase, try again for /path/to/key" as of OpenSSH_9.3p1)

Comment: I do not understand why you would need both `SSH_PASS` and `SSH_ASKPASS` to supply the passphrase to `ssh-add` ?

Comment: @user5359531 SSH_ASKPASS points to the program to run to supply the password; SSH_PASS is used by the program to return the password.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `script(1)` as a mini-`expect`.

On Linux:

```
{ sleep .1; echo password; } | script -q /dev/null -c 'ssh-add /path/to/identity'
```

On BSD:

```
{ sleep .1; echo password; } | script -q /dev/null ssh-add /path/to/identity
```

You may want to increase the delay (`sleep .3` or `sleep 1`) if the right hand of the pipeline is slow to start. For anything more complex, use [`expect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html). Do not use `sshpass` since it's really no better than `script` and itself subject to [races](https://serverfault.com/a/1005485/487680).

Comment: You're right about the flag, I don't know why that came to mind; maybe it's a different tool that takes -p as password(?)  I can't remember. Anyways, you're right

Comment: Could you break down the first part of the expression, and how the solution works? I'm not sure why the sleep call

Comment: Yes, `sshpass`. See the updated answer, I think the BSD syntax works in MacOS, too.

Comment: The `sleep` is to give time to `ssh-add` to start, print its prompt and turn echo mode off on the pseudo-terminal created by `script`. Like with any pipeline, both sides of the pipeline are started in any order, and are run in parallel, _at the same time_.

Comment: For this kind of timing problems (which also badly affect `sshpass`), see this [Q&A](https://serverfault.com/a/1005485/487680).

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco please con/infirm if the BSD `script` syntax also works on MacOS as it does on FreeBSD, since I have no MacOS to test on (it should, according to the manpage). So I could correct it before leaving. Thanks.