# How about add passphrase into .bashrc

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting

I added a script in my .bashrc to start ssh agent, but the passphrase is asked directly after logging, so I need to have my long password with me, is it possible to adding into the script and run it automatically?

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
 eval `ssh-agent -s`
  ssh-add
fi
```

Comment: why don't you use password-less ssh-keys instead?

Comment: finaly I removed thew passphrase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a passphrase to ssh-add without triggering a prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571741/how-to-pass-a-passphrase-to-ssh-add-without-triggering-a-prompt)

Comment: Thank you, got it